# How to Change generated textbox.text using textbox.textchange event

Tags: c#

### How to access the textbox.text from the other method?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
    textBox.Text = "";
    textBox.TextChanged += textBox_TextChanged;
}

static void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Text = "0";
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an example of what exactly you are trying to do? I can't quite tell from the post title/ description.

Comment: If "other method" refers to the event handler, the `sender` arg always refers to the control related to the event.  Also, you will want to read up on *scope* - *where* you declare a variable determines where it can be referenced or how widely it is available.  If you declare a variable (or object variable) locally to a click event, that is the only place it will be available

Comment: I want to create a new textbox by pressing the button. and then everytime the textbox.text == "" then replace it with "0". I couldnt access the textBox.text because it is not in the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the sender to TextBox type and use a boolean to avoid re-entry (not necessary but good smell):

```
private bool IsUpdatingTextBox = false;

static void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  IsUpdatingTextBox = true;
  ((TextBox)sender).Text = "0";
  IsUpdatingTextBox = false;
}
```

Don't you want to set the text to "0" in `button_Click`and `textBox.Enabled` to false? In this case you can change the BackColor to Window for the appearance.

Comment: i just want to prevent the textbox from empty. thats why everytime the user erase all the text. it will replace with "0". but i think this works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    textBox.Text = "0"; 
}
```